# If else (set maximum to end at a set value)

Tags: r, if-statement

How can I set a loop to run to a maximum value (Dend)? 
I just want to see how fast and deep it will grow but I want to set a maximum to say that it can't grow beyond Dend.

I get an error stating

```
  In if (D == Dend) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Code

```
 D0 <- 0 
 Dend <- 4200

 r <- 5 growth rate

 days <- 1000 
 n_steps <- days*1 


 D <- rep(NA, n_steps+1)
 D <- D0

  for (time in seq_len(n_steps)){  
   if (D == Dend){
   break}  else
    D[time + 1] <- r + D[time] 
   }

   D

   plot(-D, las=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can be achieved with `seq` without any loops :

```
D <- seq(D0, Dend, r)
```

---

If you have to use `for` loop you can use :

```
for (time in seq_len(n_steps)){ 
    temp <- r + D[time] 
    if (temp >= Dend) break
    D[time + 1] <- temp
}
```

---

We can also use a `while` loop :

```
i <- 1
while(TRUE) {
  temp <- r + D[i] 
  if(temp > Dend) break
  i <- i + 1
  D[i] <- temp
}
```

Comment: well I need it to be in the loop because there is a time factor and I need to add more parameters that will influence the growth over time.

Comment: @LR55 Updated the answer to use `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you. That added a [time] component to my original code but its not working because it still calculated D beyond 4200 when it needs to stop running then. When I extract D, it goes up to 5000. It needs to stop at 4200..

Comment: @LR55 It didn't go beyond 4200 for the example which you have shared so it makes it bit difficult to understand where and how exactly it is failing. Updated the answer changing `for` loop and also added `while` loop option.

Comment: Oh I know the problem.. In my code, Dend is predicted from the max depth for a site so max <- extract(location, site) Dend <- max. So in the example above, I gave 4200 as max depth but in my code Dend is extracted from bathymetry data and it doesn't seem to want to break the loop! Weird. If I use Dend <- 4200 its works but if I say Dend <- max it doesn't work...

Comment: I have no idea what might be missing in the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `for` loop, it might be something like below

```
for (time in seq_len(n_steps)){  
  if (tail(D,1) >= Dend)  break
  D[time + 1] <- r + D[time] 
}
```